# Integrate paypal 'Buy now' button programmatically

Tags: asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-sandbox

In my site I am integrating paypal buy now button programmatically.

this is what I have:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" style="margin-top: 30px;">
<!-- Specify a Buy Now button. --> 
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />

    <!-- Identify your business so that you can collect the payments. --> 
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@email.com" /> 
    <!-- Specify details about the item that buyers will purchase. --> 
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Your items." />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value='@Model.OrderId' />
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value='@Model.Total' />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="DKK" /> 

    <!--Don't want any shipping address. -->
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1"/>

    <!-- Specify a URL for the payment confirmation page and a page that is displayed
         if the user cancels a transaction. Also specify a URL that PayPal can post IPN
         messages to (see explanation below). --> 
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://example.com/Order/Complete/" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://example.com/Order/Cancel/" />
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="" />

    <!-- Do not prompt customers to include a note with their payment. --> 
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />

    <!-- Display the payment button. -->
    <input type="image" name="submit"
        src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif"
        alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online." />
    <img src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif"
        width="1" height="1" alt="" />
</form>
```

Now I have few questions that I didn't find any answer yet by googling and also I saw the paypal documentation but didn't really find anything :(

1. When I go to paypal site, it does not show the options to pay by credit card. It only shows payment option who have paypal account and option to create a new paypal account and pay. How do I make it show the option to pay by credit card??
2. In the paypal site at time of payment, it shows my email address. But I want to show my customer my business name not my email. How do I do that?
3. After I pay with my paypal account, it does not automatically redirect to my page even though I have a value in the 'return' field. Do I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option to allow buyers to pay with a credit card is only available to confirmed and verified PayPal accounts. The "business" value you provided above isn't linked to a PayPal account - it may not be the one you're using but it's the only information I have available at the moment.

There are some country restrictions for both the buyer and seller as well.

To show the business name you would need the "business" value to be a confirmed e-mail address linked to a Business PayPal account.

Just defining the "return" variable will not have buyers automatically returned to your site. You need to have Auto-Return enabled in the receivers account.

Comment: Hi..Thanks for the reply. I understood two of the answers but the redirect one. Do I have to set up an auto redirect link in the paypal web site? The option is available only when I create a button in the paypal but I am not creating a button using the wizard provided by paypal. I am putting all the params manually in my code.  Did you get my point? or am I not understanding the flow?